# Will Terminal show a progress bar when I copy with "cp"?

Tags: terminal

Is is possible to display a progress bar when copying files in Terminal using cp?

Comment: …you could also consider using `rsync` instead.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with an overall progress bar without installing any third party tools? Maybe a script or something?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can use rsync instead.

```
rsync --progress /copy/from /copy/to
```

Comment: Speedwise, which is faster, rsync or cp?

Comment: If all files being copied do not exist in the destination I don't think there will be a noticeable difference. If some of the files do exist in the destination then it will vary because rsync does some checking. Rsync will usually (but not always) be faster in that case.

Comment: Using `rsync -P /copy/from /copy/to` is equivalent to `rsync --partial --progress /copy/from /copy/to` which will display the copy progress, as well as resume the transfer if it is disconnected.

Comment: And just like cp, it needs the `-r` flag to make it not skip directories

Answer (score 45):

During `cp`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> displays the current percentage (on macOS at least)

Comment: that's awesome!

Comment: The reason this works is because `Ctrl-t` sends `SIGINFO` signals in the same way that `Ctrl-c` sends `SIGINT` signals. You can e.g. use a loop in another shell to repeatedly `kill -INFO` the process in question if you don't want to keep pressing the keys. Because it's a signal, it works with other utilities too, e.g. `dd`. `Ctrl-t` and `SIGINFO` are inherited from BSD.

Answer (score 2):

If you are copying large files or directories using cp, you can open up 'Activity Monitor', go to the 'Disk' tab and look for the process 'cp'. Here you can keep track of how many bytes have been written since the last boot, giving you a rough idea of the progress. (OS X 10.10).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
   strace -q -ewrite cp -- "${1}" "${2}" 2>&1 \
      | awk '{
        count += $NF
            if (count % 10 == 0) {
               percent = count / total_size * 100
               printf "%3d%% [", percent
               for (i=0;i<=percent;i++)
                  printf "="
               printf ">"
               for (i=percent;i<100;i++)
                  printf " "
               printf "]\r"
            }
         }
         END { print "" }' total_size=$(stat -c '%s' "${1}") count=0
```

It's not perfect, but it works... drop that in a directory path and name it something similar..

Comment: Wait...how do I get that to run???

Comment: I don't recall whether OS X had an `strace` command at the time this answer was written (July 2011), but it definitely doesn't today.

Comment: Any ideas how to run this on macOS?